How to produce input/output audio devices with Realtek RLC215 Codec after transition from Windows 11 to Ubuntu
I recently had an update on Windows 11 which rendered my audio input and output useless. I made the transition to Ubuntu OS with the hope of fixing this problem. I was able to discover that the audio drivers I am using are Realtek RLC215 which are not supported in the list of kernels.org.
However, by modifying my alsa-base.conf file to add the line options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0 at the bottom, I am able to produce audio output by disabling the microphone. When this is added, using pavucontrol, I can see the audio input and output as my internal speakers/microphone. However, obviously you cannot use the microphone. When this line is not added, there are no input/output devices at all. Please let me know if anyone has some ideas to try. Thanks!
My computer specs are:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Hardware: HP HP EliteBook 840 G6
Processor: Intel Core i7-8665U x 8
Memory: 32.0 GiB
